# find all local maximum from the matrix

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Please write a method in Java which will receive as input a matrix (int[][] matrix) and which should find all local maximum from the matrix. A local maximum is such a number in the matrix that is greater than all its immediate neighbors. The method should return the List of locations of all local maximum numbers found.

i tried this code to make this but don't know if this idea is correct or not the code

```
private static List<Integer> findLocal(int[][] matrix) 
{

    List<Integer> locals = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {

            if (i < matrix.length - 1 && j < matrix[0].length - 1) {
                if (matrix[i][j] < matrix[i + 1][j] && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i][j + 1] && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i + 1][j + 1]) {
                    locals.add(i + j);
                } else {

                }

            }
        }

    }

    return locals;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What part of this algorithm do you find difficult? We won't just code something for you; we're here to *help*.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried so far and where is the concrete problem?

Comment: Probably he doesn't know where or how to start at all?

Comment: @mort: sorry, but then he should have asked "How to start..." or "Where can I find..." and not "Please submit the source code of the method". It indicates that he doesnt have made up his mind on his own, and I am really really really tempted to answer such a question with some obfuscated code, which outputs "I am too lazy to do my homework on my own" when run.

Comment: @flolo: I totally agree with you. But I think that given a question like this one it is hard to tell whether the person is just to lazy to deal with the task or just doesn't know where to start and what questions to ask. IMHO, one shouldn't discourage people if the latter is the case.

Comment: again: try to ask more specific questions. Does your code run? Try to run it with a simple dummy test matrix and validate your results!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now it seems you have come with an idea up, and it is basically a working idea.

It has just one flaw: The neigborhood your are looking at is wrong: for a point (i,j) the (von Neumann) neighbors are (i+1,j), (i,j+1), (i-1, j), and (i,j-1).

So when you check for this point it should in general work, BUT: You have to take special care of the borders. As you have no -1st and no n+1th column/row you have when you are there take that neighbor point out of consideration. How you handle it, depends on how you want to treat it: Should the neighborhood wrap around, should the border have a constant value, should it be treated as -infty?

Comment: +1 I forgot about the borders thing!

Answer (score 2):

You write

```
if (matrix[i][j] < matrix[i + 1][j] 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i][j + 1] 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i + 1][j + 1]) {
```

which checks for whether the element is smaller than three of its neighbours. What about the other five neighbours? Let's check them, too:

```
if (matrix[i][j] < matrix[i + 1][j] 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i+1][j-1] 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i+1][j+1] 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i][j + 1] 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i][j - 1] 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i-1][j-1]) 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i-1][j]) 
    && matrix[i][j] < matrix[i-1][j+1]) {
```

This assumes you want to check the element's 8 immediate neighbours, i.e. straight and diagonal. Adjust if this is not what you want.

Also the requirement is finding the local maxima. This identifies a local minimum. Change `<` to `>`.

Another thing is that `locals.add(i + j)` doesn't do what you think it does. If element (i=3,j=4) is a local maximum, then you're saying `locals.add(7)`, which clearly is not what you want.

Comment: You took Moore neighborhood - not sure what the original poster wants - I used von Neumann as it is shorter (and I am lazy ;-). +1 I didnt saw the wrong relation

Answer (score 1):

> I think that there is no need for 8 comparisons for every matrix
>   element. You should take two extra arrays:

1. `MATRIX[n+2][n+2]`: It will contain yout input matrix with an extra
   layer of all INT_MIN's(So, that every matrix element has all 8
   neighbours).
2. `Mark[n+2][n+2] = {0}` (You should only have to visit the elements in
   the input matrix which are not marked) If a matrix element is
   declared as a local minimum, you should marks all its neighbour in
   the Mark[][] vector.

> By doing so, complexity will remain O(n^2) but no. of comparisons will
>   be minimised.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store i and j separately to remember the position of an element correctly. Thus,

```
List<Integer> locals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

won't work. 
You could use

```
 List<Integer[]> locals = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```

instead. And to add the position of a newly found local maximum, use

```
 Integer[] localMax = {i, j};
 locals.add(localMax);
```